# resize issue on nav, refresh fixes it

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have been stuck on this issue all day.
I am trying to make a header that has a logo on the left and a list on the right.
Then I want it to resize with the nav below the logo.
I GOT THIS TO WORK but when I resize back to a large width, my `nav` is still below the logo.

I am new to web development so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Website</title>
    <!-- links -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style copy.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body class="body">
    <!--  Main Menu  -->
    <div id="mainMenu" class="mainMenu">
      <div class="logo"></div>
        <nav class="rightThenMid">
          <ul>
            <li class="active first"><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

AND CSS

```
body {
  clear: both;
}

.body {
  clear: both; 
  margin:0;
  padding:0; 
}

.mainMenu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #121212;
  z-index: 10; 
}

.mainMenu nav {
  height: 90px;
}

.mainMenu nav ul {
  height: 100%;
}

.mainMenu nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  font: 11px/6.36em "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.25em;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mainMenu nav ul li.first a {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.mainMenu nav ul li.last a {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.mainMenu nav a {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff; 
}

.mainMenu nav ul li a:hover, .mainMenu nav ul li.active a {
  color: #6159c1;
}

.rightThenMid {
 float: right;   
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  background-image: url('img/companyLogo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: auto;
}

ul, li, nav, p {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  outline: none;
  font-size:100%;
  vertical-align:baseline;
  background:transparent;
}

nav ul,ul,ol {
  list-style:none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 700px) {
  .body {
    clear: both; 
    margin: 0 auto; 

  }

  .mainMenu {
    height: 140px;
  }

  .mainMenu nav ul {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
  }

  .rightThenMid {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    float: none;
  }

  .logo {
    display:  block;
    margin:auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 70px;
    background-image: url('img/companyLogo.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give your `.logo` a `float: left` without the media query and a `float: none` within the media query.

I think the problem is, that you just gave `.rightThenMid` a float and not `.logo` as well.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wXEsS/)

```
.logo {
  ...
  float: left;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 700px) {
    .logo {
      ...
      float: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes? I could reproduce the error in a fiddle in chrome. Didn't try FF.

Comment: You are correct, in FF it works for me as well. But not in Chrome, http://jsfiddle.net/wXEsS/1/

Comment: Yea chrome is messed up

Comment: @rezen__ You are welcome, glad I could help. This seems to be a bug within the webkit engine (Chrome and Safari). But now you know how to fix it.. ;)